# Angular this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart always null

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-directive

inside an Angular directive I want to check if input text is selected,so I use 
this.el.nativeElement.selectionEnd and this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart but all are null,is there any clue? thanks

```
export class myDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
     console.log(this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's an input element / textrea?

Comment: yes  <input  type="number" ...>

Comment: `selectionStart` does [not apply](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#do-not-apply) to `<input type="number" />` elements and will return null.